# How to change Info.plist for other countries in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am building an iOS game with Unity, but I am not able to localize the app display name or the Camera Usage string.

I was trying to follow a few tutorials how to change the Info.plist for different languages, but none of it works.

In the Info.plist, I added

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>de</string>
</array>
```

and I added two folders: de.lproj and en.lproj, the first one containing InfoPlist.strings:

```
NSCameraUsageDescription = "Deutsche Beschreibung";
CFBundleDisplayName = "Deutscher Name";
CFBundleName = "Deutscher Name";
```

But on my German phone, it still displays the name and the camera description in English.
Does anyone know how to correctly localize that?

Answer (score 0):

After some hard times, I found out that you have to drag the de.lproj and e.lproj inside the hierarchy on the left in the Xcode project, otherwise Xcode would just ignore the files.